# Do not run the project play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

When I start a project browser, which offers play framework error takes off

```
Not a valid command: backgroundRun
Not a valid project ID: backgroundRun
Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
Not a valid key: backgroundRun
backgroundRun
             ^
```

What should I do?

Comment: which version of activator/sbt are you using? how are you starting that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no a valid command 'backgroundRun' in sbt/activator console.
Maybe you can try use '~run'.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlayConsole